# Git mark file as binary to avoid line separator conversion

Tags: git, binaryfiles

I have a text file with sample data which I want to put under Git control (on Windows). How can I tell Git to treat this file as binary, so it does not convert line separators (like for the other/text files in the repository).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Write this in .[gitattributes](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) (in the file’s directory or higher up):

```
myfile.bin -text
```

See the manual for more explanation.

Comment: Please clarify that you do not mean the shell variable `$PATH`. Could be mistaken.

Answer (score 5):

While `-text` in `.gitattributes` did not worked,

```
myfile.bin binary
```

did.

Comment: Binary is a shorthand for `-crlf -diff`

Comment: What's the difference between this and `-text`?