# prevent merge of ascii file in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

Is there a way to tell Mercurial that a specified ascii file should be completely overwritten rather than merged during future updates, similar to the treatment of a binary file?

Git handles this using .gitattribues, as described here: [Git mark file as binary to avoid line separator conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994811/git-mark-file-as-binary-to-avoid-line-separator-conversion). Is there a Mercurial equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `merge-patterns` (in the `hgrc`). This allows you to specify `internal:other` as the merge action.